# How to find generic type

Tags: java

How to check `Class<?>` object type?

I have method:

```
public void method(Class<?> class1){

}
```

I want to check if `class1` is `InputStream.class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class1 == InputStream.class
```

or

```
InputStream.class.isAssignableFrom(class1)
```

depending on whether you want to check equality or that you have a class object whose instances obj will obey `(obj instanceof InputStream)` without necessarily being exactly an `InputSream`.